# swift build: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Darwin'

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to run the 'example-package-dealer' from the Swift Package Manager repo but it's failing to build resulting with this error:

```
/usr/local/include/string.h:26:10: error: 'dpkg/macros.h' file not found

#include <dpkg/macros.h>

<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'Darwin'
```